# Get the count in the column

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want a query that gives count of region repeated where the date is 'april2018'
expected output by query

**Table displayed**

```
+---------+--------------+
| region  |     Date     |
+---------+--------------+
| africa  |    april2018 |
| africa  |    may2018   |
| africa  |    may2018   |
| america |   jan2018    |
| america |   jan2018    |
| africa  |    april2018 |
| africa  |    may2018   |
| africa  |    may2018   |
| india   |    jan2018   |
| india   |    jan2018   |
+---------+--------------+
```

**Expected Result**

```
+----------+---------+
|  region  |  Count  |
+----------+---------+
|  africa  |       2 |
|  america |       0 |
|  india   |       0 |
+----------+---------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `case when` with count

```
select region, coalesce(count(case when Date = 'april2018' then 1 end),0) as count
from tablname
group by region
```

Answer (score 0):

You can execute below query to get the result, as asked for.

```
SELECT Region, COUNT(*) AS Cnt
FROM Region
WHERE Date = 'April2018'
GROUP BY Region
```

Comment: it is giving count africa 2 but i want count of america and india also

Comment: got it. Updated my answer. Sorry for my misunderstanding

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, Thanks. I got confused. thanks for updating my answer again. appreciate your help.

Comment: But, OP wants to display, India and America also, even though, they dont have 'April 2018'. In my case only, Africa will be displayed. I think I should update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have added a primary key to get your expected result

```
mysql> select * from region_date;
+---------+-----------+----+
| region  | date      | id |
+---------+-----------+----+
| africa  | april2018 |  1 |
| africa  | may2018   |  2 |
| africa  | may2018   |  3 |
| america | jan2018   |  4 |
| america | jan2018   |  5 |
| africa  | april2018 |  6 |
| africa  | may2018   |  7 |
| africa  | may2018   |  8 |
| india   | jan2018   |  9 |
| india   | jan2018   | 10 |
+---------+-----------+----+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select count(sub), inn.region from 
        (select 
          i.region, 
          (select s.date from region_date s where   s.id = i.id  and s.date = 'april2018' limit 1)  as sub, 
          date 
         from region_date i) as inn group by region;
+------------+---------+
| count(sub) | region  |
+------------+---------+
|          2 | africa  |
|          0 | america |
|          0 | india   |
+------------+---------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another simple approach:

```
SELECT Region, SUM(Date='april2018') as Count
FROM TableName
GROUP BY Region;
```